Searching for story featuring a scene of a man manipulating the weather to cause a laborer to change his clothing
The scene I recall involves someone playing God by using some kind of futuristic device to control the weather as he observes a laborer on a screen. He demonstrates that he can exert control over the man by, I think, causing him to begin to sweat as the sun goes up, remove his coat, then put it back on again as it becomes cold and snowy and windy.
I think there may be some kind of time dilation occurring as well.

The North Wind & the Sun

Was this a short story? And when did you read it?

There's a scene in Richard Garfinkle's "All of An Instant" (which features altering history) when a fellow is trying to change clothing styles in a society by making changes to the history of the society (clumsily).

The story seems similar to Aesop's Fable https://aesopsfables.org/F6_The-Wind-and-the-Sun.html but naturally there is no technological weather control device in such an old story.

There is a brief scene as you describe in Walking on Glass (Ian Banks, 1985), but it's not a significant part of the plot.
